# How to change the unit of the axes of a figure representing an array (X pixels for 1 kilometer for example)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using matplotlib I was able to display this array:

[image]

I want to change the unit of the x and y axis: for example 40 pixels to match 1 kilometer and put a tick every 1 kilometer (every 40 pixels).

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first get a scale for the image, by setting the `extent` argument. So if you knew e.g. that your image is 10.4 km wide and 7.2 km high, you'd set

```
ax.imshow(data, extent=(0, 10.4 ,0, 7.2))
```

If on the other hand you'd knew that 40 pixels are 1km, you would calculate the extent from the image shape like this

```
y,x = data.shape
res = 40. # = 40 pixels per kilometer
ax.imshow(data, cmap="terrain", extent=(0,x/res ,0,y/res ))
```

This will now automatically set the ticks' positions, which is usually fine to prevent overcrowded axes.
If you want more control over the ticks, you can use the usual methods for tick placement, e.g. either set them manually `ax.set_xticks([1,2,4.5])` or using a locator.

Below is a full working solution.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(360,520)
fig, ax=plt.subplots()

y,x = data.shape
res = 40. # = 40 pixels per kilometer
ax.imshow(data, cmap="terrain", extent=(0,x/res ,0,y/res ))

ax.set_xlabel("distance [km]")
ax.set_ylabel("distance [km]")

# option 1 (you need to know how many ticks to put beforehands)
#ax.set_xticks(range(14))
#ax.set_yticks(range(10))

# option 2 (automatic ticklabel placement)
import matplotlib.ticker
# put a tick every kilometer
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(1))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

EDIT following comments that it misses the OP's needs:

the simplest way is to just set the xtick positions and labels, with a bit of care on the steps:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some data to show (replace this with your map)
M = numpy.random.rand(400, 320)
plt.matshow(M)
ax = plt.gca()
px_per_km = 40.0
tick_step_in_km = 1.6
ticks = numpy.arange(0, ax.get_xlim()[1], px_per_km*tick_step_in_km)
tick_labels = ["{}km".format(t/px_per_km) for t in ticks]
plt.xticks(ticks, tick_labels)
# same procedure for yticks if desired.
plt.show()
```

EDIT - patched the solution with ticker subpackage, but it is a bit clunky.

the ticker formatters are often more flexible (e.g. when zooming), with only a little more work:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FuncFormatter

majorLocator = MultipleLocator(px_per_km*tick_step_in_km)  
def scaled_fmtr(s, pos, px_per_km=px_per_km):
    return "{:.1f}km".format(s/px_per_km)
majorFormatter=FuncFormatter(scaled_fmtr)       

ax = plt.gca()
#ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(majorLocator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(majorFormatter)

plt.show()
```

for more information see the [ticker/locator docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html).

Comment: The answer I am looking for was provided by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest but thank you for answering ! (+1)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest good point, I didn't get it right first time :)  I think the `extent` method is a nice way to handle this